# Web-push fcm endpoint 404: Requested URL not found on this server

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push, push-api

I am subscribing users to web-push notifications. I have followed the documentation on [web.dev](https://web.dev/notifications/). When I try to send a web-push message through my backend service(using rust web-push crate) to push-service endpoints, FCM or chrome returns 404 page not found(tested through postman), while the same client side & server-side code works for Other browsers like Firefox and Microsoft edge.

Is there any difference on how chrome subscribes to web-push compared to other browsers?